# Ubuntu Software turned into Snap Store after updates

Tags: updates, 22.04, snap-store

After I've installed latest updates on Ubuntu 22.04, Ubuntu Software turned into Snap Store:
[image]

I made some experiments with four Ubuntu 22.04.1 - 4 versions, clean setup on VirtualBox and updates install.
Every time Ubuntu Software not changing and still the same.

How can I fix that?
I mean bring back Ubuntu Software instead of Snap Store.
Or at least somehow change icon and app title.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has really changed just a combining of the two previous Ubuntu Store applications.

In the image below, the arrow points to a drop down menu which allows you to select the version required, in this case, snap store versions are listed first but further down the list is the deb version. Just select the version you want.

[image]